Login de terceros MAUI Razor
Tengo un proyecto Maui Blazor Hibrido con api y servidor SQL Server, en mi pagina de inicio de sesión quiero meter un boton para iniciar sesion mediante google y no se como puedo hacerlo , he creado credenciales y puesto los valores en el app settings pero no se como llegar a usarlo en mi pagina de inicio de sesión.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Hay ejemplos de autenticacion con google.. probaste alguno?

Sin código no te podemos ayudar.
